Black and white movie that changes to color at the end
Fifteen years ago I saw a movie which was black and white for most of it, but at the end it changes to color. 
It was about a guy, that was either a spirit or invisible for some reason... It was similar to It's a Wonderful Life but still different. I think that it was produced in the USA.
I remember that at the end there was a scene of the guy and his girlfriend running out of a building, getting in a car and going away. The car was red and I think it was from the 50's. The whole film looks rather oldish... I suppose that the movie is from the 50's as well.

Is it Pleasantville? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleasantville_(film). It was released in 1988 and the plot has little similarity to what you describe, so perhaps not.

@Livrecache 1998.  And just because the OP said 15 years ago doesn't mean the film only came out then.  2002 is sufficiently close to 1998 for it to be that film.

@Tim, Thanks.  My bad – a typo. I also belatedly realised I hadn't registered the second para of the OP at all. I need caffeine!

The black & white switching to colour and the "spirit" part of the question remind me of "Wings of desire" but I haven't seen it in a while and I'm not sure for the other elements of the question. And it doesn't take place in the 50's either.
